# Flattening a time-varying hierarchy in SQL Server and getting the distance between each pair

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I'm trying to flatten a tree by getting the distance between each ID and each of the ancestors within the tree. While that itself wasn't too hard (thanks stackoverflow), I've been having trouble trying to create a CTE that appropriately handles the fact that my tree changes as a function of time.

I'm trying to get a list of each ID/ancestor pair in the tree at any given point in time, as well as the distance between that ID the ancestor.

Any of the SQL Server wizards out there have an idea what to do? Because I keep trying and I keep getting obviously wrong values.

Sample data

IN:

```
ID    AncestorID    StartDate     EndDate
--------------------------------------------
2              1    2000-01-01    2000-01-04
3              1    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
4              3    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
5              4    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
4              1    2000-01-03    2000-01-04
3              4    2000-01-03    2000-01-04
```

Out:

```
ID    Ancestor       Distance    StartDate     EndDate
------------------------------------------------------
 2           1              1    2000-01-01    2000-01-04 
 3           1              1    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
 3           4              1    2000-01-03    2000-01-04
 3           1              2    2000-01-03    2000-01-04
 4           3              1    2000-01-01    2000-01-02 
 4           1              2    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
 4           1              1    2000-01-03    2000-01-04
 5           4              1    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
 5           3              2    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
 5           1              3    2000-01-01    2000-01-02
 5           1              2    2000-01-03    2000-01-04
```

Comment: Is your last line `ID` is correct ? Because in third line `ID = 4`, `AncestorID` is `3` and in last line `ID = 3`, `AncestorID` is `4` I dont think that is logically correct

Comment: That's where it gets to be a pain in the ass.

The two entries for 4 are applicable on different days. 4->3 on on the 1st and 2nd, 4->1 on the 3rd and 4th, and 3->4 only applies on the 3rd and 4th.

In short, on the 1st/2nd the path is 4 -> 3 -> 1, whereas on the 3rd and 4th the path becomes 3 -> 4 -> 1 because both 4 and 3 have direct ancestors that change at the same time.

Comment: We can use `Recursive CTE` for this but the last line will make it go for infinite recursion. I prepared a demo for you http://rextester.com/MPBZ10904.

Comment: Ah, but that's there's the rub. ;) I need to build something that only follows Child->Parent links for when the timeframes overlap. Unfortunately my dataset is filled with pairs like this where the 2 entries swap positions in the tree. Thanks for the help, i'll keep at it.

Comment: Hm... either I am missing something or the provided data is not completely correct. I created an example, but I receive less records. For ID 5 I receive the ancestors 1, 2 and 3 - but 1 only one time...

Answer (score 0):

Following an example I created - might not be very pretty, but it seems to work. Only thing I don't get: where does your second Output for ID 5 with AncestorID 1 come from?

However, this is what I got so far:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, AncestorID int, StartDate date, EndDate date);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, 1, '2000-01-01', '2000-01-04')
                     ,(3, 1, '2000-01-01', '2000-01-02')
                     ,(4, 3, '2000-01-01', '2000-01-02')
                     ,(5, 4, '2000-01-01', '2000-01-02')
                     ,(4, 1, '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04')
                     ,(3, 4, '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04');

DECLARE @MinAncestorID int = (SELECT min(AncestorID) FROM @t);

WITH cteBase AS(
  SELECT @MinAncestorID ID, 0 AncestorID, CONVERT(date, '1900-01-01') StartDate, CONVERT(date, '2999-12-31') EndDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ID, t.AncestorID, t.StartDate, t.EndDate
    FROM @t t
    JOIN cteBase c ON t.AncestorID = c.ID AND t.StartDate >= c.StartDate AND t.EndDate <= c.EndDate
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT ID, AncestorID, StartDate, EndDate
  FROM cteBase
  WHERE AncestorID > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT b.ID, a.AncestorID, a.StartDate, a.EndDate
  FROM cteBase AS b
  JOIN cte2 AS a ON a.ID = b.AncestorID AND a.StartDate >= b.StartDate AND a.EndDate <= b.EndDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte2
ORDER BY 1, 2
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: The 5->1 distance change appears because of the intermediate change of 4 from 4->3 to 4->1 on the 3rd. The path from 5 to 1 changed from 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1 to 5 -> 4 -> 1. I'm tempted to just take a list of distinct start and end dates from the entire table and just let the CTE run once at each date.